# Vivaldi 1.13 goes full screen when opening link from external app

Tags: vivaldi

With the last update of Vivaldi (1.13) I noticed it maximises the window every time I open a link from external application (e.g. Slack). Is it an option that could be turned off? Can I change this behaviour? I don't want it to change the window size when opening a new link.

I'm on Max OS 10.12.6.

I also verified it's only Vivaldi, when I switch default browser to e.g. Chrome and open link from Slack, it doesn't resize the window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [Snapshot 1.14.1042.3](https://vivaldi.com/blog/snapshots/exorcism-vivaldi-browser-snapshot-1-14-1042-3/) there is a regression for the MacOS version mentioned which was fixed:

> [Regression][Mac] Minimizing Vivaldi window causes subsequent windows
>   to open maximized (VB-35317)

My impression is that there seem to be some issues with the windows size (maximize, restore size) at the moment (comments, changelog of fixed bugs), so the behavior you observe might be a bug.

My recommendation is: Stay tuned for the next release 1.14 (which also brings sync).

Comment: Strange that it's a known bug, even fixed already, but I couldn't find any info about it on google. Thought it's only me, or I'm the only one that doesn't like it ;) Anyway, thanks for the snapshot, works like a charm!

Comment: Have you also seen the [1.14.1047.3 snapshot](https://vivaldi.com/blog/snapshots/lingering-processes-on-macos-vivaldi-browser-snapshot-1-14-1047-3/) as it has some more bugfixes for the MacOS version?! I just linked that old snapshot as a reference for the changelog I quoted.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think I need the newest one. I'll stick to the snapshot and then switch back to the stable release when it's released.